# Unplugging electrical outlets/plugs causes HDMI to lose signal on TV connected to PC?

Tags: hdmi, tv

I have a Sony A90J LED tv (65") and it's connected to my PC using an HDMI cable. Problem is when I unplug a nearby plug/extension outlet, the hdmi on the tv loses signal, then it gets worse, every seconds or so it loses signal then comes back again, then again, then again.. it never stops. It is quite annoying. As I tried connecting it to my smaller led TV (55") it works just fine. I was wondering if it's the hdmi cable that's the problem (maybe shielding? or I need a better quality cable since the one I am using is the one that came with the TV), or something with the PSU of my PC maybe not able to handle the load of the TV? (because I have a pair of active speakers connected to the optical out of the TV and audio is outputted through that). Sometimes when I plug in an electronic device and the socket sparks for a second, it affects the signal of the TV too. Nowadays, without the unplugging situation, the problem just surfaces. I uninstalled my GPU driver with DDU then re-installed the Nvidia driver again (RTX 2070), moved the HDMI cable away from electrical wires.. and it's still the same. Does anybody know what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Though I can't diagnose what's wrong with the information you gave, a general suggestion for similar issues is to plug the PC, TV, sound bar, and other devices that are cabled together into a single power strip, preferably one with RF suppression, or at least surge protection, to reduce AC mains glitches. For two-prong, unpolarized, plugs (ungrounded), you might experiment with inserting in either direction.

Comment: Sounds like a bad HDMI cable or an incorrect HDMI cable setup, as HDMI cables are shielded - how long is the cable, what type of HDMI cable (active or passive), and are any extensions/adapters being used?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a grounding problem.

Comment: Potentially a "ground loop" problem. Solved as above. Also I personally wouldn't plug anything I valued into a "socket that sparks for a second" Sounds like cheap gear all around. Active speakers draw their own power, the optical is just a signal transport. Similarly there is no "load" on an HDMI cable. Your PC PSU and TV PSU both do the things they're designed for.

Comment: Seek advice of an electrician.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I solved the problem. It was indeed a bad HDMI cable. Bought a more expensive one and it didn't happen again. Never thought cables mattered until now.